# Can someone explain the way Ubuntu manages networking?

Tags: networking, network-manager

Configuring kvm networking these past days taught me two things, one that Ubuntu doesn't use `Network-manager` as the default network manager(as I kept tweaking settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` without those changes being properly reflected, and that `netplan` is something of a network renderer that uses different configuration files.

This pushed me to understand linux networking better and I came across more tools like `ip` and `brctl`. My question is, these utilities manage the same networking interfaces. So who decides which tool's configuration reflects on the system?

What exactly is the difference between `netplan`, `Network-Manager` and `ip`? If they all manage the same interfaces using different configuration files, why not have just one utility like `ip` which is ubiquitous among linux distros?

system: 18.04 LTS Ubuntu Desktop

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you on, and more importantly, is that a server version or a desktop version?

Comment: @Jos sorry I should've mentioned that. 18.04 LTS desktop.

Answer (score 0):

> Ubuntu doesn't use Network-manager as the default network manager(as I
>   kept tweaking settings in /etc/network/interfaces without those
>   changes being properly reflected,

Why should they? Except for *lo* the loopback interface, `/etc/network/interfaces` is deprecated in 18.04 and later in favor of *either* (but not both) Network Manager or netplan.

In almost every case, in a desktop environment, Network Manager does a fine job. I recommend that you revert the changes you have made to `/etc/network/interfaces` as wel as `/etc/netplan/*` and make any changes you require in Network Manager.